# What's the difference between the public transport types?

Tags: cities-skylines

Other than theming - I'm wondering what the functional differences are in the different public transport types.

Some of them are pretty obvious:

- Buses don't need anything built.
- Metros don't take up space.
- Monorails, metros, aren't subject to road traffic congestion.

But basically- what I'm wondering is why one would ever build monorails over metros.

Like monorails are more difficult to place/take up more room. Are they faster? It's just that they come with better stations?

Some specific things I'm wanting to know:

- What is the speed of the various transport types.
- What is the capacity of the various transport types. (ie. are some going to subject to congestion faster than others?)

Answer (score 1):

This question is mostly opinion based due to the nature of the game but based on facts, the biggest issue with monorails is noise pollution. Placing monorail tracks and stations in the middle of residential areas will increase noise pollution and cause a drop in health.

Regarding costs, take a look at the table below. As you can see, the differences are minor.

[image]

I cannot find a source but I read on reddit once that the monorail is faster on longer distances, but I cannot find any data to back it up.

For me it mostly comes down to aesthetics. Metro is mostly invisible but with the monorail you can put avenues with monorail tracks which sort of makes the city "prettier".

You can also have a look at the this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/8nca1v/a_look_at_transportation_costs_capacity/) about transportation, which might help you.